# Spawning language server with cmd: `clangd` failed

Tags: neovim

I have a c project and I would like to use the feature of LSP in Neovim such as `gd` (go to definition).

I follow each of these materials to configure LSP

- [langserver.org/](https://langserver.org/)

  Konwing that I need to use *clangd*.
- [nvim-lspconfig/doc/server_configurations.md#clangd](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#clangd) and [clangd.llvm.org/installation](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation)

  To install *clangd* on Ubuntu (18.04).
- [TJ DeVries's guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puWgHa7k3SY),

  To configure nvim-lspconfig, being like

  ```
  require('lspconfig').clangd.setup{
    on_attach = function()
                  print("Hello C/C++!")
                end
  }
  ```
- [clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup)

  I use [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) to produce *complile_command.json*

However, I've encountered some problems.

1. Following the guide in [clangd.llvm.org/installation](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation), I execute `sudo apt-get install clangd-10` to install *clangd* (`sudo apt-get install clangd-12` will result in `E: Unable to locate package clangd-12` even though I have executed `sudo apt-get update`). But when I want to check the version of *clangd* by executing `clangd --version`, I got `Command 'clangd' not found` as it is not installed yet.
2. After executing `bear <my_build_command>`, I got the *complile_command.json*. But when I open .c file in the project, I got the information: *Spawning language server with cmd: `clangd` failed. The language server is either not installed, missing from PATH, or not executable.*

--

I think the problem may result from 1. After Googleing the related information and tried to reinstall clangd, `clangd --version` still result in the same: `Command 'clangd' not found`.

Do I missing something or what? Any one can give me a help? Thanks.

Comment: I have the impression that your current problem is more related to the installation of clangd on Ubuntu than related to Vim and the relation between clangd and Vim. I recommend you to contact some clangd knowledgeable people first (although some could also follow this site ;-) ).

Comment: Hi @VivianDeSmedt Thanks for replying. Finally, I fixed it somehow. For someone else might need the information, I follow the answer part of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60901658/clangd-is-not-found-in-vim-using-neoclide-coc-nvim), and then `clangd --version` gives me the version information.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Did you also solved the integration with Vim?

Comment: Yes. In my case, installation of clangd is just the last thing to make LSP working on Neovim.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad you have found a solution to your problem :-) Welcome to Vim.

Comment: Thanks for replying and giving the idea. :-)